# Java: Mapping 1d array to Bitmap

Tags: java, android

I have following 2D array that holds color intensity values for RGB channels.

```
// create a 2d array for colors
int[][] rgbColors = {
            {255, 0, 0}, //red
            {0, 255, 0}, //green
            {0, 0, 255}, //blue
        };
```

I have another 1D array:

```
// Data array
int [] data = {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2}
```

I want to reshape the `data` array into a `3x3 Bitmap Image` such that all 0 values are mapped to the red, all 1 values are mapped to the green and all 2 values are mapped to blue colors in the resultant Bitmap. In other words, the resultant Bitmap would have three lines with red, green and blue colors respectively. The color values are given in `rgbColors` 2D array. What is the most efficient way to achieve this?

**Edit:**

I tried following but it did not work and produced an empty white image.

```
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(data, 3, 3, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the documentation(I have no expertise at all in Android), I think that changing the `data` array to

```
    int[] data = {-65536,
    -65536,
    -65536,
    -16711936,
    -16711936,
    -16711936,
    -16776961,
    -16776961,
    -16776961
};
```

will work but you need to read the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap#createBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) to know the meaning of the parameters.

Comment: That worked and I understand that these are color intensities which Bitmap understands. Can you kindly tell me what these values are called and where can I look for color table in this format?

Comment: @HaroonS.I'm no expert but these are the formal [specs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ColorSpace.Named#SRGB) and the values are present in this [Constants](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color#constants_2) section.